# AS3 Performance difference between separate function files and static methods

Tags: performance, actionscript-3

Can anybody enlighten me on the performance differences between using function files vs static methods.

ie:
myFunction.as - is just an as file that contains one function "myFunction()"
you would then import that file and call myFunction();
or
Utils.as has a static method: public static function myFunction(){}
you would then import the class and us Utils.myFunction();

Does the former suffer the same package lookup hits as static classes?

My guess is that it would only be lighter if my static class had more methods and I only used 1 method as it would still import the entire class.

Comment: Static methods tend to be slower in execution time - if youre interested in performance, check out this blog: http://jacksondunstan.com/. However, guessing that you are reasonably new to object-orientated ActionScript? (from the terminology you are using) i suggest that you use whichever way is easiest for you until your experience grows. When to use static methods/classes is a matter of great debate - even whether they should be used at all.

Comment: @LeeBurrows is correct here. Do what is easiest for now, especially since this subject is widely debated. I personally only use static methods for generic utilities that are not specific to a certain class. I know a lot of people argue against that, even. In the end, it's personal preference. Static methods are slightly slower (only because of lookup times), but the difference is so small it will only really be noticed in large quantities

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm not really "new" to object-oriented AS and I could just be using silly terminology. Neither are easier than the other. Originally I was using a static class, but then a co-worker mentioned the other method of using single .as files where the name of the file matches the method name inside it. Starling does this quite a bit and flash does as well at times so we were wondering if doing it that way was better for performance.

Comment: @LeeBurrows - also if you don't mind. What terminology are you speaking of. I'm always looking for "proper" terminology.

Comment: eg: "function files vs static methods" - the two are not really comparable - for instance, you can have a static method in a 'function file' (usually called "include file" when not a class file). But dont worry about this technical stuff - the best way to learn is to make mistakes; the next game you make will be all the better for it.

Comment: @LeeBurrows Oh I see. Yeah I meant to say Static class (with static methods), but thank you for the clarification on include file. I've worked with them before but it's new to me to see include files with only one method in them. ie: getDistance.as having one method getDistance():Object - again - thank you.